# Is if(!a) faster than if(a==0)?

Tags: performance, if-statement, compilation

This may be a pretty stupid question, but I couldn't find an answer to it.
I was wondering which code would be the fastest:

```
int a = 0;
if(a){
    //do something
}
```

or

```
int a = 0;
if(a==0){
    //do something
}
```

I wrote it in C, but I'm also wondering for other languages if there's a common behaviour. I was also wondering if the gain in performance (if there's one) was worth the loss in lisibility.

Comment: Don't worry about things like that.  If performance is important, you profile your entire application and address the bottlenecks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A clarification

I assume you meant `if(!a)` vs `if(a == 0)`, since `if(a)` is actually asking if `a` is nonzero! If so, then the answer follows.

### Explanation

No, the two will generate equivalent output with most compilers. This should hold true for almost any language with similar syntax for this case, not just C.

Also note that modern compilers are very good at optimisation, and thus more complex examples of equivalent behaviour and different syntax are also likely to compile to the same result.

Optimisation is not likely to play a part here, though, as the snippets are so simple as to be syntactically equivalent, and both clearly just compile to a `jne` instruction jumping over the code in the if block.

### See for yourself!

Using the [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) Compiler Explorer, you can actually check if, say, GCC or Clang outputs the same assembly for these snippets.

https://godbolt.org/z/XvTKej has two source tabs and two compiler tabs. As you can see, the two source tabs contain the two snippets in question, `if(!a)` and `if(a==0)`, and the two compiler tabs (both the same GCC version) list out the assembly produced - first source tab for the first compiler tab, and the second for the second. The assembly produced for both versions is the same!

You can switch the compilers to check if the same holds true for different versions of GCC or for Clang or any number of small and/or obscure compilers.

### Which should you use?

Currently, style consensus is that for most cases, you should use `if(!a)` and not `if(a == 0)`. This is most obvious in the case where 0 is an exceptional value for `a` meaning that something is *not* the case, for example this:

```
// Check status data
if(!status) { // Status check failed
    // handle failure case
} else if(status == 1) { // Status OK
    // handle OK case
} // ...and so on for other cases
```

Though you may want to use a `switch` for this kind of thing, I hope the point I'm making comes through.

This kind of syntax may be less ideal if, for example, 0 means that something *is* so - then the use of `!a` which reads 'not `a`' might be more confusing than just using `a == 0`. So don't blindly follow a rule regarding this, but most of the time `if(!a)` is a good choice.